# Play 2.3.X Security headers are gone when adding CACHE_CONTROL header in doFilter

Tags: scala, http-headers, playframework-2.3

My Global.scala:

```
object Global extends WithFilters(SecurityHeadersFilter(), new GzipFilter())
              with GlobalSettings {

  override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>
    action(request).map(_.withHeaders(
      CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private",
      PRAGMA -> "no-cache"
    ))
  }
}
```

All security headers (X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, ...) are gone if I tries to override doFilter with CACHE_CONTROL. How can I enable security headers as well as CACHE_CONTROL at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing:

```
object CacheCtrlHeadersFilter extends EssentialFilter {
  def apply(action: EssentialAction) = new EssentialAction {
    def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader) = {
      action(requestHeader).map { result =>
        result.withHeaders(
            CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private",
            PRAGMA -> "no-cache"
          )
      }
    }
  }
}

object Global extends WithFilters(
  SecurityHeadersFilter(),
  CacheCtrlHeadersFilter,
  new GzipFilter()) with GlobalSettings {
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for overriding header for specific actions, this link will help you. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/xLChBorfZLc/bzaEVU3Ylc0J

Answer (score 0):

Well... I am not sure about anything else... but your headers are missing because you are overwriting them.

To fix overwriting of headers you can change this as follows,

```
object Global extends WithFilters(SecurityHeadersFilter(), new GzipFilter())
          with GlobalSettings {

  override def doFilter(action: EssentialAction) = EssentialAction { request =>
    action(request).map( x =>
      // get the ResponseHeader
      val originalResponseHeader = x.header
      // get Headers from the ResponseHeader
      val originalHeaders = originalResponseHeader.headers
      // create a map of extra headers
      val extraHeaders = Map(
        CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private",
        PRAGMA -> "no-cache"
      )
      // add extra headers to existing headers
      val finalHeaders = originalHeaders ++ extraHeaders
      // convert map to list
      val finalHeadersList = finalHeaders.toList
      // return with final headers
      x.withHeaders( finalHeadersList : _* )
    } )
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The result is the same. Headers from SecurityHeaders are still missing.

Comment: Well....  If they were not present in the first place... Then those will be missing...

Comment: But SecurityHeaders suppose to insert default headers. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SecurityHeaders